# How to set read only for only one buffer

Tags: buffers, argument-list

I'm using vim with some plugins, such as Nerdtree, YCM, to build an coding environment.

Now I want to achieve this:

When I execute the command `vim`, a file containing some ASCII image, will be loaded automatically.

Well, this is only for good looking.

What I've done is to add a line in the file `~/.bashrc`: `alias vim=vim -o ~/.vim/ascii_img`.

It works but I want to make the buffer of `ascii_img` read only to prevent the file `ascii_img` getting changed accidently.

Then I changed the line above in `~/.bashrc`: `alias vim=vim -ro ~/.vim/ascii_img`.

However, now all of files become read only.

Is it possible to make only the specific buffer read only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternate method is to modify your alias (I prefer functions, so I’ll show both):

```
# alias
alias vim='vim +"setlocal readonly" ascii'

# function
vim () {
  command vim +'setlocal readonly' ascii "$@"
}
```

The issue here is I’m not sure if vim is ok with options/flags that come *after* the first file argument.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add to your vimrc an autocommand which will be executed every time you read the file and will be used to set the `'readonly'` option on the file:

```
augroup readonly
    autocmd!
    autocmd! BufReadPost ascii_img setlocal readonly
augroup END
```

See [`:h autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd) and [`:h 'readonly'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27readonly%27)